# Que tipo de "focus" é esse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava a  ler artigos neste site, http://zenorocha.com/, e selecionei um conteúdo e a página se fechou no conteúdo e deu um "focus" especial, vasculhei um pouco na internet mas não achei nada similar, isto é um script ou é de autoria do dono, como reproduzir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### É o plugin [`Fokus`](http://lab.hakim.se/fokus/), desenvolvido pelo [Hakim El Hattab](https://github.com/hakimel):

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor nisi, vulputate vitae magna id, luctus lacinia nisi. Donec finibus dolor ut erat posuere tincidunt. Praesent aliquam sodales ex. Integer non commodo justo, sit amet vestibulum enim. In sem augue, dignissim ac venenatis et, aliquam vel dolor. Donec vitae neque id massa venenatis pellentesque nec eget arcu. Etiam in sagittis risus, eu sodales sem. Mauris tempus vehicula gravida. Aliquam dapibus egestas quam, vel tincidunt lacus viverra vitae. Ut rhoncus, sem in pretium fringilla, mi quam porttitor purus, nec viverra dolor lorem sit amet nibh. Sed dapibus consectetur orci, a vehicula leo rhoncus eu. Ut a nunc tortor. Nullam hendrerit eu mi at mollis. Sed quis tortor vitae erat bibendum viverra. Mauris vel neque elit. Aenean at interdum leo, vitae lacinia massa.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus a dolor sed lorem dignissim efficitur a et neque. Praesent fermentum, mauris vitae tincidunt pellentesque, orci mi vehicula est, semper auctor magna sem vitae diam. Suspendisse eu dignissim metus. Donec congue nibh eget erat pellentesque porttitor. Etiam dui velit, rhoncus et nisl vel, iaculis varius purus. Integer lobortis enim nec sapien maximus posuere. Vivamus fermentum risus urna, vitae sodales enim feugiat consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin venenatis posuere arcu, sed molestie ipsum convallis eget. Praesent pretium velit non egestas sagittis. Integer pellentesque mauris at mauris scelerisque ultricies. Donec interdum rutrum libero, et sodales orci faucibus in.
</p>

<script src="http://lab.hakim.se/fokus/js/fokus.min.js"></script>
```

#### Muitos outros plugins do mesmo criador podem ser vistos aqui: http://lab.hakim.se/